# Jitsi meet in flutter not working on android 12

Tags: android, flutter, android-12, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I have integrated jitsi_flutter for group calls. But, the app is not installed in the latest android supported version 12.

Here is the link for jitsi_flutter, which I have used.
https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet

I am getting this issue when trying to run the app on android 12 supported devices.

```
adb: failed to install E:\Flutter\flutter_jitsi\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl502165721.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #110): org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

Answer (score 5):

If you still have issue with that, add this service to your manifest:

```
<service
       android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
       android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

If this working let me know, thanks.

Comment: where should i add it

Comment: i get unexpected element <service> found in <manifest>.

Comment: you can add on your manifest

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/issues/356

Looks like the devs are working on it.

Comment: Devs are not responding to that library. I am stuck here. Already added an issue related to this on github.

Comment: No need to worry. I am working on the migration right now.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Migrated but having some problem related to theme

Comment: Do you think this can be resolved?

Comment: I'll update here and GitHub once I found a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/saibotma/jitsi_meet_wrapper  This jitsi library is supported in android 12. I want to get participants' info and chat info same as android and ios SDKs provide but flutter doesn't have the same methods. Can you add those methods available in this example demo? @Harish

Comment: add this in the manifest: manifest > application > after activity>add this

Answer (score 0):

```
**This works for targetSdkVersion 31**
**Paste below code in AndroidManifest.xml**
<service
   android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```